# Would sparks from connecting power adapter to DC jack cause issues to a circuit?

Tags: power-supply, inrush-current

When connecting a power adapter (19V) to a circuit through a wall mount DC jack, I get these **[sparks](https://ibb.co/9rVXQpw)**.
Would this cause any damage to the circuit, and if so what would be the solution other than not connecting the power adapter when its switched on.

Circuit: [image: circuit]
Power adapter:

[image: power adapter]

Comment: It will erode the contacts over time. And stresses the electrolytic caps. But I have never seen actual device failures immediately following such events. You can prevent it with inrush current limiting in your device

Comment: Why don't you just turn on the power supple AFTER making the connection?

Answer (score 3):

Holy,

There is definitely a design issue there.

Sparks will create high EMI as current rushes and can definitely cause damage to the electronics.

EMI is generated by the large inrush current that goes through the cable and PCB trace, this can then damage sensitive components, mostly silicon ones like fets and Uc.

The sparks also can generate large voltage spikes that can propagate through the circuit.

It will also destroy the connectors over time.

The simplest solution is to plug it in with the supply powered off.

The alternative would require opening the device to add some in-rush protection.

Comment: Would be good if you expanded on what sort of damage can it cause to the electronics.

Comment: @HandyHowie as to what possible damage could be is many and varied. I had an instance where the transient high current pulse found its way through the main micro and killed it. On some other piece of equipment it could be benign or somewhere in between.

Comment: Maybe add that to your answer.

Comment: Thanks, we just added a switch next to the wall mount plug and this prevents the sparks